# what is the difference between the methods getvalue() and value() in spark broadcast variables

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast

I created broadcast variables in spark java and called destroy() methods on them 
when i used get value() method  i am still able to access the variables but when I used value method it is throwing error which is correct

Answer (score 1):

The broadcast variable is read-only

From their documentation

"After the broadcast variable is created, it should be used instead of the value v in any functions run on the cluster so that v is not shipped to the nodes more than once. In addition, the object v should not be modified after it is broadcast in order to ensure that all nodes get the same value of the broadcast variable (e.g. if the variable is shipped to a new node later)."

Answer (score 0):

They are both to get the broadcasted value,but the value function will check if this broadcast is valid first. So I think we'd better use value instead of get value.